# Tem como inflar uma classe?

Tags: android

Existem muitos métodos que você infla uma layout.xml mas eu precisa inflar uma classe dentro de uma tab, alguém sabe o que posso fazer? estou no sufoco aqui.
Para inflar layout.xml uso este código:

```
if(this.getTag() == "formulario3"){
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario3, container, false);
}
```

Porém criei um formulário dinâmico só por código Java e não estou conseguindo inflar.

Answer (score 0):

**daniel12345smith**, supondo que a classe guarde objetos/propriedades do tipo `View`. Então, ao invés de "inflar" (que é uma opção exclusiva para trabalhar com os `xml`), você pode chamar métodos desta classe que inserem no `Context` desejado estes views relacionados à esta classe.

**Exemplo**

**`PrincipalActivity.java`**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    Contatos.carregaContatos(PrincipalActivity.this);
}
```

**`Contatos.java`**

```
public class Contatos
{

    public static void carregaContatos(Activity activity)
    {
        // declara TextView
        // note que "activity" agora pode procurar uma view da activity PrincipalActivity.java 
        TextView textView = new TextView(); // ou "this.minhaTextView", whatever

        // codigo que insere uma View guardada e gerida por esta classe "Contatos"
        // note que "activity" agora pode procurar uma view da activity PrincipalActivity.java 
        LinearLayout linearLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.info); 
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

    }

}
```

E assim sucessivamente. A ideia é manter a "logica" (domain logic e business logic) separada (infelizmente o Android segue um padrao View-Controller) e temos que nos virar como podemos.

Comment: vlw mas eu não tenho nada de xml no meu projeto, esse é o problema.

Comment: Opa, então, tudo bem! A ideia é esta mesma. Criar os Views como OBJETOS (por codigo) em suas classes e depois adicionar na Activity que você quiser, tudo por codigo. Note que `TextView textView = new TextView(); ` do meu exemplo acima não existe em XML nenhum...e ele foi adicionado ao container RelativeLayout por código, na linha abaixo. Mas pra isso, a ActivityPrincipal teve que chamar o método `Contatos.carregaContatos(PrincipalActivity.this);` e passar sua activity como parâmetro. Foi só pra exemplificar a que sua Ideia na pergunta pode seguir este fluxo. Aliás, eu faço tudo assim hehe.